# $state.go not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am using `$state.go` inside the controller of the my abstract state and it is not working. I am using an $ionicPopup and on click of the button I want to navigate to another state. It shows no errors in the console. Here is my code.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'ContactsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.browse', {
      url: '/browse',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html',
          controller: 'BrowseCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      views: {
        'signup': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
          controller: 'signupCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.playlists', {
    url: '/playlists',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
        controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/browse');
});
```

And here is my Javascript code from the `AppCtrl`

```
$scope.showCartPopup = function(){
    $scope.cartItems = $localStorage.cart;
    $scope.costSum = 0;
    $scope.cartItems.forEach(function(element, index){
      $scope.costSum += Number(element.price);
    });
    $scope.costSum = $scope.costSum.toFixed(2);
    console.log($scope.cartItems);
    var templateString = "a long template string here";
    $ionicPopup.show({
      title: 'Your Cart Items',
      template: templateString,
      scope : $scope,
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Continue'
      },{
        text: 'Checkout',
        type: 'button-assertive',
        onTap: function(e){
          $timeout(function() { $state.go("app.signup") });
          //return $q.reject("Rejection message!");
        }
      }]
    }).then(function(res){
      if(res == 'signup'){
        console.log(res);
        $timeout(function() { $state.go("app.signup") });
      }
    });
```

I used `$timeout` when `$state.go` was not working at all but even it didn't help. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your onTap callback being invoked at all? Set a debugger; to find that out. Also, try going to the state from your dev tool console. angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state').go('app.signup') and see if that works.

Comment: Yes the onTap callback is being invoked but the $state.go is not doing anything noticeable. I tried placing `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state').go('app.signup')` in the dev tool console and it just returned me a promise object. No visible changed in the app.

Comment: I also tried navigating to and fro another state using `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state').go('app.contacts')` and it worked. Just not able to navigate to `app.signup`.